# What components of a neuron are impermanent during the host organisms's lifespan?

Tags: neuron

I understand that a neuron's dendrites can die, and new ones can grow. To what extent are other components of a neuron impermanent during the host's lifespan? Do we need to go to the atomic level to find impermanence in the soma and axon?